# Exploding from a String to a Curl based String - PHP

Tags: php, curl

I came across an issue while trying to separate values returned from a API request, returned by a curl based string.

code:

```
....code..
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $outputArray=explode(" ",$output);
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    print_r($outputArray);
```

Now if I am to `print_r` this I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 Success 79714042 79714042 BTd0Dm )
```

My goal is to separate those values and turn them into arrays, so:

```
Array ( [0] => 1, [1] => success...etc..
```

By doing the `explode(" ", $output);` 
this should work fine but it does not?

If I take a normal string lets say I do this:

```
$output="1 Success 79591908 79591908 mEg0gN";
$outputArray=explode(" ",$output);
print_r($outputArray);
```

The output is the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Success
    [2] => 79591908
    [3] => 79591908
    [4] => mEg0gN
)
```

Now I went further to see the var_dump of these values and found that the string I made above is only 35 characters where as the returned curl value comes out to be a length of 180 characters?

Ideas and thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

David

Comment: can you echo $output so we can see the response

Comment: i believe you actully want `explode(" ", $output[0]);`